# How to design customisable sliderInput in R Shiny application?

Tags: r, shiny, slider

I have a skewed data and would like to design slider with predefined set of values. The key bins for data looks like - "Less than $100K", "$100K - $1M", "$1M - $3M", "$3M - $5M", "More than $5M").

Please, help me to design this kind of selector

```
sliderInput(
  "revenue", "Revenue",
  min = 0, max = max_revenue,
  value = c(0, max_revenue), 
  step = 1000, pre = "$", sep = ",")
```

Thanks!

Comment: How about `sliderText` from [shinyWidgets](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")

target_range <- c('0','100k','1M','3M','5M','Max') 

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  sliderTextInput(
    inputId = "revenue",
    label = "Revenue:",
    choices = target_range,
    selected = target_range[c(1,2)]
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "revenue_data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$revenue_data <- renderPrint(str(input$revenue))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```